# PHP: Why $url with PATH_INFO dosent work?

Tags: php

I have problem with this:

```
$url = isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) ? explode('/', ltrim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/')) : '/';

if($url == '/'){

    require_once __DIR__.'/Models/index_model.php';
    require_once __DIR__.'/Controllers/index_controller.php';
    require_once __DIR__.'/Views/index_view.php';

    $indexModel = New IndexModel();
    $indexController = New IndexController($indexModel);
    $indexView = New IndexView($indexController, $indexModel);

    print $indexView->index();

} else{
```

On xampp server this work. But on web hosting no. Php only do else. Dont load index.

Comment: Have you checked what `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` actually contains on the server?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i try this "echo $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];" but this dont show anything

Comment: Btw, if the path info is `/`, the variable `$url` will be an array with one empty string as value, not a string since you're exploding it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Can you give me little example how can i do this?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson when i do something like this: "if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/'){"    works :D

Comment: I've posted an answer that should work for you.

Comment: What do you mean by "work"? What happens on those two environments - what **should** happen, what doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is that if `PATH_INFO` contains `/`, you're exploding that string which gives you an array while you're checking if it equals a string.

All you need to do is check the value straight away:

```
// Get the path if it exists, or / if it doesn't
// PHP 7+ version
$path = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ?? '/';

// PHP 5.x version (if you need this, you should really update your PHP version asap)
$path = isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) ? $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] : '/';

// Let's just compare the value straight off
if ($path == '/') {
    // Start page
} else {
    // Something else
    // Explode the path here if you need to
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that `??` is PHP 7+ exclusive ternary.